# Groupby sum, sort and transpose

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new in pandas and groupby functionality.
I have Dataframe as shown below, which is a transaction data of customer as shown below, I want to find out the top two `Dprtmnt` per `Cus_No` based on their total `Amount`.

```
Cus_No     Date     Dprtmnt          Amount
111     6-Jun-18      AAA              100
111     6-Jun-18      AAA              50
111     8-Jun-18      BBB              125
111     8-Aug-18      CCC              130
111     12-Dec-18     BBB              200
111     15-Feb-17     AAA              10
111     18-Jan-18     AAA              20
222     6-Jun-18      DDD              100
222     6-Jun-18      AAA              50
222     8-Jun-18      AAA              125
222     8-Aug-18      DDD              130
222     12-Dec-18     AAA              200
222     15-Feb-17     CCC              10
222     18-Jan-18     CCC              20
```

My expected output is shown below.

```
    Cus_No     Top1D Top1Sum    Top1_Frqnc  Top2D   Top2Sum  Top2_Frqnc
       111      BBB     325          2        AAA      180       4
       222      AAA     375          3        DDD      230       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` and `size`, sort and get top2 by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), last reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and create new columns names by `map` and `join`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Cus_No','Dprtmnt'])['Amount']
        .agg([('Sum','sum'),('Frqnc','size')])
        .sort_values('Sum', ascending=False)
        .groupby(level=0).head(2))

df = (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str), append=True)
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14, step=1)
   Cus_No Dprtmnt1  Frqnc1  Sum1 Dprtmnt2  Frqnc2  Sum2
0     111      BBB       2   325      AAA       4   180
1     222      AAA       3   375      DDD       2   230
```